# login redirect to different page than given under " Menu Item Login Redirect"

Tags: joomla-3.x, login

I have set up a menu Item Users-> Login Form.
There I set the "Menu Item Login Redirect" to Home. However the site redirects me to "/shop-pages-2/register-2/profile". My homepage does not have a shop (jet).

Where does this "/shop-pages-2/register-2/profile" overwrite my "home" setting. The page with the Login form is the right Menu item. I tested this with adding pre- and post text to the Login form using the same Menu item where I set "Menu Item Login Redirect".

(I am using Joomla 3.7.5 and the Porto Template.)

EDIT: I have updated to Joomla 3.8.1 and I still have the same issue

Comment: Please try updating to Joomla 3.8 and see if the issue still persists.

Comment: Updating to 3.8 isn't an option right now because the whole admin view crashes within the update,  it's an issue with SP page builder I'm also working on.

Comment: If you update SP Page Builder to the latest version aswell, you won't have the issue mentioned with the admin backend. I say this cause 3.8 had routing changes, so it may fix the issue. Else take a look at the `.htaccess` file to see if you can see any rewrite conditions for `/shop-pages-2/register-2/profile`

Comment: Okay thank you. I'll update thua question after I updated sp pagebuilder and joomla

Comment: 3.8.1 has just been released and includes a "Redirect plugin not redirecting correctly" fix which might help. For details see: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/17997

Comment: Thx.  I'll look into it after I sorted the page builder issue

Comment: I have updated joomla to 3.8.1 and I still have the same proble @NeilRobertson

Comment: @Webdesigner I have AcyMailing Akeeba BAckup, K2, jDownloads, Unite Slider, SP Pae Builder, VirtueMart, VirtueMartAIO, but not all are in use

Comment: Can you disable SEF URL's for a moment and test it again, what is the URL that you get e.g. `index.php?option=...` I'm very sure it has to do with VirtueMart

Comment: Any just to be shure that it has nothing to do with the template, with to protostar template and test it again. BTW what Version of VirtueMart do you use?

Comment: I get ...com/shop-pages-2/register-2/profile but I want to redirect to home. I can't disable SEF because we had to change the server for it to work, changing it back isn't an option. I'm not using virtueMart. so disableing this extention might fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain first, how the redirect happen after login.

File: components/com_users/views/login/default_login.php

```
<?php $return = $this->form->getValue('return', '', $this->params->get('login_redirect_url', $this->params->get('login_redirect_menuitem'))); ?>
```

The page will redirect to:

- Value of `return` parameter in the request; if empty then
- Value you set in your menu item for `login_redirect_url`; if empty then
- Value you set in your menu item for `login_redirect_menuitem`

So the final redirect depends on the same order of values above.

If none of the above values are available, the final return value will be your profile page (what is happening in your case). The code for this in:

file: components/com_users/controllers/user.php

```
// Set the return URL if empty.
if (empty($data['return']))
{
    $data['return'] = 'index.php?option=com_users&view=profile';
}
```

Please make a note that; the redirect url that you set in your menu item must be internal url or selecting the ID of the menu item. Internal urls starts with `index.php`.

Example `index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=myview`